# Unable to get function named "kareoke" to work

Tags: javascript, function, toggle

Function doesn't work when its name is "kareoke"

I have created a function by the name of "kareoke", and try to call it on click event but it worked just once then i get that error message in my browser console:

> Uncaught TypeError: kareoke is not a function at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick

But when I changed the name of the function, it worked seamlessly. By the way I noticed that I misspelled karaoke but isn't a function supposed to work no matter what name I give to it? I didn't get why the function didn't work when its name is "kareoke".

```css
.active {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="active" id="main-music">
  <audio src="https://amazingaudioplayer.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingaudioplayer/1/audios/In the Moment of Inspiration.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>

<div class="hidden" id="kareoke">
  <audio src="https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s0gKkQ7HPhtN&command=download_mp3" controls></audio>
</div>

<button onclick="kareoke()">Show Hide</button>
<script>
  function kareoke() {
    mainMusic = document.getElementById("main-music");
    kareoke = document.getElementById("kareoke");
    if (mainMusic.className === "active") {
      mainMusic.className = "hidden";
      kareoke.className = "active";
    } else {
      kareoke.className = "hidden";
      mainMusic.className = "active";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vary your names more.

The first time you call the function, it is indeed a function.  But what does that function do?  Among other things, this:

```
kareoke = document.getElementById("kareoke");
```

At the window scope this is over-writing the `kareoke` variable with something else, something that is not a function.  So any future attempt to invoke it will result in an error.

Don't re-use the same variable names.  (At least not in mixed scopes and not in such a small program.)  And, as good practice, keep scope local to the function by declaring variables with either `var`, `let`, or `const`.  Something like this:

```
function kareoke() {
  let mainMusic = document.getElementById("main-music");
  let kareokeElement = document.getElementById("kareoke");
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer! Now I got where the problem comes from.